# jqGrid renders fine, but cannot access getGridParam

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

jqGrid renders fine, but I cannot access getGridParam, it throws

> Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

```
 function updateGrid(inmateID) {

        $(".loading").show();

        var grid = $("#jqGridDiv")[0];

        $.ajax({
            url: "<%= AdminPath %>WebMethods/WebService1.asmx/GetUsersJSON",
            data: '{ webMethodParam: \"' + inmateID + '\" }',
            dataType: "text",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
                $(".loading").hide();
            },

            success: function (data) {

                //debugger; 
                var tmp1 = $.parseJSON(data);
                var ncicList = $.parseJSON(tmp1.d);

                grid.addJSONData(ncicList); //works

                var data = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'); //Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid'

                $(".loading").hide();

            } //end ajax success
        });  //end ajax
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error exist because you try to use `var data = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');` where `grid` is DOM of `<table>` element instead of jQuery wrapper (see `var grid = $("#jqGridDiv")[0];`). You need use `var data = $(grid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');`.

Even if you would use `ar data = $(grid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')` you can get empty array `[]`. It's important *which other jqGrid options you use*. You use old `addJSONData` API which can don't fill local data and so can don't fill `data` or `_index` parameters of jqGrid. It's important to know which `datatype` you use in the grid and whether you use `loadonce: true` (in case of usage `datatype: "json"`).